# Chance button in flash AS 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, random

i would like to ask this community for some help with my end-course project. I am making a tell tale game where if you click a button there is a chance of you moving from frame 1 to frame 2 or there is a chance of lets say 30% of going to slide 3. This is the script i am using right now.

```
stop();
Button1_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Shoot_1);

function Shoot_1 (event:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndPlay(2);
}
```

I apologize for the poor structure of this post, this is my very first post.

PS: My goal is to make it go and play frame 2 at a % chance or go and play frame 3 at a % chance.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be use random number to check if it's greater than 7 because you want 30% of chance to get to frame 3.

```
stop();
var result:uint
Button1_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Shoot_1);

function Shoot_1 (event:MouseEvent) :void
{
    result = randomIntBetween(1, 10);

    if(result > 7)
    {
        gotoAndPlay(3);
    }
    else
    {
        gotoAndPlay(2);
    }
}

var percentage:String = result + '0%';

trace(percentage);

function randomIntBetween(min:int, max:int):int {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
```

Comment: but how can i alter the % chance ? do i just change the number where the 7 is? otherwise i thank you alot. And will this work if i paste it under my script?

Comment: @GregFlash u want get the percentage?  just get from the result value. i will update the post

Comment: Thank you, you are a life saver. does the 0% chance mean i have 0% to go to 3 or 2? or is it just a variable?

Comment: @GregFlash 0? the range of random number should be from 1 to 10

Comment: @GregFlash try to place the result in side of the function shoot_1